# Able to click & get the inside value of edit box but unable to sendkeys operations

Tags: selenium, webdriver, keyword, sendkeys

I am able to get the value inside the texbox
I am able to click inside the text box,
unfortunately unable to type data using sendkeys operation or robot action

[HTML Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmZet.png)

Comment: Can you share code which you are trying to do sendkeys? Also your marked screenshot has span , that is not input tag. Do you want to send text in span?

Comment: Can you post your code..with the using url..?/

Comment: //Fill email sender details
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='templatesTab']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/span"));
    elem.click();
        
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.switchTo().activeElement();
    
    elem.sendKeys("Many Happy Returns of The Day");

Comment: yes i want to send the text into span...